# Send data to multiple fragments using Serialization

Tags: android, android-fragments, serialization, pojo

I'm new here so please bear with me. I'm trying to send some data to multiple fragments from MainActivity using Serialization method in POJO. In MainActivity I open a new fragment(FragOne) and I'm able to get data but when I open a new fragment(FragTwo) from FragOne the app crashes with NullPointerException. I searched how to send data using serialized POJO to more than one fragment but there were no results. So, if anyone can help me solve this, I would be grateful. Thanks.

```js
public class FragTwo extends Fragment{

    TextView name, position;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragtwo, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        position = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.pos);

        Spa spa = (Spa)getArguments().getSerializable("spa");


        name.setText(spa.getName());
        position.setText(spa.getPosition());
    }
}
```

```js
public class FragOne extends Fragment{

    TextView name, position;
    Button btn;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragone, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        position = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.pos);
        btn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.change);

        Spa spa = (Spa)getArguments().getSerializable("spa");

        name.setText(spa.getName());
        position.setText(spa.getPosition());

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragTwo two = new FragTwo();
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).replaceFragment(two);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment){
        FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        t.replace(R.id.frame, fragment).addToBackStack(null);
        t.commit();
    }

    public void SerializeMethod(View view){

        Spa spa = new Spa();
        spa.setName("Ricky");
        spa.setPosition("Android Dev");
        Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
        mBundle.putSerializable("spa", spa);
        FragOne one = new FragOne();
        one.setArguments(mBundle);
        replaceFragment(one);
    }


}
```

```js
public class Spa implements Serializable{

   private String name, position;

    public String getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(String position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set arguments while switching from fragment one to fragment two

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
            mBundle.putSerializable("spa", spa);
            FragTwo two = new FragTwo();
            two.setArguments(mBundle);
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).replaceFragment(two);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there any way in which I add info only at one place and can fetch it anywhere? @SaravInfern

Comment: Hey its working now. I'll accept this answer. Thanks so much.